# Cannot hide element in bootstrap with multiple classes

Tags: jquery, hide, element

I am trying to show/hide element using jquery on a bootstrap element with col-xs-12 class:
I try to add/remove the hidden class when i press on a thumbnail.

This is my basic page layout:

```
 <section id="BA_images" class="row">
              <div id="BA_1" class="">
                <div class="twentytwenty-container"> <img src="../_images/products/cards/sample_1.jpg" /> <img src="../_images/products/cards/sample_2.jpg" /> </div>
              </div>
              <div id="BA_2" class="col-xs-12 hidden">
                <div class="twentytwenty-container"> <img src="../_images/products/cards/sample_3.jpg" /> <img src="../_images/products/cards/sample_4.jpg" /> </div>
              </div>
              <div id="BA_3" class="col-xs-12 hidden">
                <div class="twentytwenty-container"> <img src="../_images/products/cards/sample_3.jpg" /> <img src="../_images/products/cards/sample_4.jpg" /></div>
              </div>
              <div id="BA_4" class="col-xs-12 hidden">
                <div class="twentytwenty-container"> <img src="../_images/products/cards/sample_3.jpg" /> <img src="../_images/products/cards/sample_4.jpg" /></div>
              </div>
            </section>


            <section id="BA_thumbs" class="row">
                    <div id="thumb1" class="current col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="../_images/products/cards/sample_1.jpg"  alt="" onclick="showHideImage(1)"/></a>
                    </div>                         

                    <div id="thumb2" class="none col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="../_images/products/cards/sample_2.jpg" alt="" onclick="showHideImage(2)"/></a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="thumb3" class="none col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="../_images/products/cards/sample_3.jpg" alt="" onclick="showHideImage(3)"/></a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="thumb4" class="none col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="../_images/products/cards/sample_4.jpg" alt="" onclick="showHideImage(4)"/></a>
                    </div>

            </section>
```

the script is this:

```
function showHideImage(thisID){
    "use strict";
    var i, thumbID, imageID;
    var thumb_prefix = "thumb_";
    var image_prefix = "BA_";
    var thumbNum = 4;
    for (i = 1 ; i<thumbNum+1 ; i++){
        //thumbs index starts with 1.
        thumbID = thumb_prefix + i;
        imageID = image_prefix + i;
        console.log(document.getElementById(imageID));
        console.dir(document.getElementById(imageID));
        if (i === thisID) {
            $('#' + thumbID).addClass("none");
            $('#' + imageID).removeClass("hidden");
        }
        else{
            $('#' + thumbID).addClass("none");
            $('#' + imageID).addClass("hidden");
            }
        }
}
```

it does not work...
can anyone help?

Comment: it is not working - it hides all the divs....

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showHideImage(id) {
  $('[id^="thumb"]').removeClass('current').filter('#thumb' + id).addClass('current')
  $('[id^="BA_"]').addClass('hidden').filter('#BA_' + id).removeClass('hidden')
}
```

Comment: thank you -i'll test it. any idea why my original one did not work? can i add/remove using the $("#ID').addClass or removeClass explicitly?